Add a stock quantity suffix in WooCommerce based on category
Based on the code here https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-stock-quantity-suffix-e-g-sq-in-kg-boxes-etc/ I have the code below that allows me to add a suffix to the quantity of products WooCommerce. Everything works perfectly with simple products. For variable products, it only displays the default suffix, even if I have set another prefix. For example, instead of showing "bax" it shows "m2". How to make it work with variable products?
Thank you in advance!
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_stock_quantity', 'wc_stock_quantity_suffix', 9999, 2 );

function wc_stock_quantity_suffix( $stock_quantity, $product ) {
    $categories = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
        $category_slug = $categories[0]->slug;

        switch ( $category_slug ) {
            case 'phone':
                $stock_quantity .= ' buc.';
                break;
            case 'accessories':
                $stock_quantity .= ' bax';
                break;
            case 'milk':
                $stock_quantity .= ' l';
                break;
            
            default:
                
                $stock_quantity .= ' m<sup>2</sup>';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // If there are no categories, we use the default suffix
        $stock_quantity .= ' m<sup>2</sup>';
    }

    return $stock_quantity;
}



For variable products, product_cat terms are associated with the parent product (the variable product that holds the individual variations), rather than the individual variations themselves. However, woocommerce_format_stock_quantity provides the product variation, not the parent product. Therefore you need to retrieve the parent product in these cases and get_the_terms on that one.
You can use the WC_Product::get_parent_id method to retrieve the parent product id:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_stock_quantity', 'wc_stock_quantity_suffix', 9999, 2 );

function wc_stock_quantity_suffix( $stock_quantity, $product ) {

    if ($parent_id = $product->get_parent_id()) $product = wc_get_product($parent_id);

    $categories = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

    // Your category logic goes here ...

    return $stock_quantity;

}

